# Docker fails to load proxy Environment variable

Tags: linux, docker, centos7

I have `Docker` version `18.06.3-ce` installed on `CentOs 8`.

My system is behind a firewall, so I tried to edit the proxy settings by adding `http-proxy` file in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` with the proper settings.

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://my_proxy:port"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://my_other_proxy:port"
Environment="NO_PROXY=<ANOTHER_PROXY>"
```

However, even after `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart docker`, the Environment settings seem not to have taken effect.

When I try

> systemctl show --property Environment docker

All I see is

> Environment=

no values or anything.

I am new to `Linux` and `Docker`, so not sure why this is appearing so. While the proxy addresses may not be working themselves, I expect at least to see these values within the `Environment` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure you Docker Client using .json file instead of using ENV vars

> Doc : https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

```
On the Docker client, create or edit the file ~/.docker/config.json in the home directory of the user which starts containers. Add JSON such as the following, substituting the type of proxy with httpsProxy or ftpProxy if necessary, and substituting the address and port of the proxy server. You can configure multiple proxy servers at the same time.

You can optionally exclude hosts or ranges from going through the proxy server by setting a noProxy key to one or more comma-separated IP addresses or hosts. Using the * character as a wildcard is supported, as shown in this example.

{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://your_proxy:port",
     "httpsProxy": "https://your_other_proxy:port",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
Save the file.

When you create or start new containers, the environment variables are set automatically within the container.
```